# Why is CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL a default setting in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

From MSDN docs:

> When SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is ON, concatenating a null value with a string yields a NULL result. For example, SELECT 'abc' + NULL yields NULL. When SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is OFF, concatenating a null value with a string yields the string itself (the null value is treated as an empty string). For example, SELECT 'abc' + NULL yields abc.

What is the purpose of this behavior? What is the utility of having it be the default setting? I understand that it can be circumvented by changing the setting or using methods like `COALESCE`, but I don't understand why this is a standard setting.

Comment: ANSI SQL compliance?

Comment: @jarlh ANSI SQL doesn't use `+` for concatenation, does it?

Comment: @hvd. I know... But same null behavior. Added a question mark...

Comment: Because operations with null yield null in standard sql

Comment: To distinguish MS SQL from Oracle ? ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of `null` as meaning "unknown". If you concatenate an unknown value with a known value, the result is still an unknown value.

This is the standard way of thinking about `null` for ANSI compliance. For more evidence of this, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)

It states that:

> SQL null is a state (unknown) and not a value. This usage is quite different from most programming languages, where null means not assigned to a particular instance.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me. When you think about the meaning of null dogmatically like that, it makes a lot of sense. Null is inapplicable data.

Comment: If your answer is according to ANSI/ISO compliance, you might want to know that searching the ANSI/ISO SQL Standard document for "null value" yields 400+ occurences ;)

Comment: It also has a definition: *"**The null value** Every data type includes a special value, called the null value, sometimes denoted by the keyword NULL. This
value differs from other values in the following respects: ..."*

Answer (score 4):

`CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx).

> In a future version of SQL Server `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` will always
>   be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will
>   generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work,
>   and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

Regarding your question this is [per the SQL Standard](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#functions-concat)

> Core feature ID E021-07: Concatenating two strings is done with the `||`
>   operator: `string1 || string2`
>
> If at least one operand is `NULL`, then the result is `NULL`.

Though SQL Server does not use the standard `||` operator.

Throughout most operations in SQL nulls propagate though there are some inconsistencies

`NULL + 3` returns `NULL` but

```
SELECT SUM(N)
FROM   (VALUES (NULL),
               (3)) V(N)
```

Returns `3` and an informational message that nulls were ignored.

If you are on at least SQL Server 2012 you can use [`CONCAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh231515.aspx) - this will treat NULLs as though they were empty strings as you desire.

Comment: If this setting is to be deprecated in future, will it be safe to use code like this

`declare @where nvarchar(max)
select @where = coalesce(@where + 'and', '1 = 1')`

to create SQL statements based on some condition? This code is assuming that `@where` is null thus `@where + 'and'` will be null so `coalesce` will return `1=1`

Comment: When `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` eventually does get forced `ON` - I hope SQL Server has a succinct, if not beautiful, alternative syntax for `COALESCE`, otherwise it's going to  be extremely tedious to have to put `SELECT COALESCE( col1, '' ) ||  COALESCE( col2, '' ) ||  COALESCE( col3, '' ) ||  COALESCE( col4, '' ) AS concated FROM tableName`. I swear the ISO SQL committee _want_ to make SQL so very painful and unappealing.

Comment: @Dai - You can already use `SELECT CONCAT(col1, col2, col3, col4) AS concated FROM tableName` for that

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes (thankfully!) but it's possible (warning: contrived scenario ahead) that in the near-future when SQL Server does support `||` syntax then also consider that some people might be contractually obligated to write ISO SQL that doesn't use any vendor-specific extensions, so they couldn't use `CONCAT` so they'd have to use `||` with gratuitous amounts of `COALESCE` and I feel sorry for those people already.