# What is the error with my select condition only show Nvarchar not null when select to datagridview c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I added new `Nvarchar` column to my table patients to store Arabic names and its working fine, but when I select the data to datagridview by using the stored procedure, it shows only the rows with Arabic names and not show the rows if Arabic name is null.

The error in the where condition when I added the `Nvarchar` column to the condition it shows in datagridview only rows with value in new column `patient_Name_Arabic`, but when I remove the column `patient_Name_Arabic` from the `where` condition then all the data showing in datagridview .

What is the error and how to show all data in datagridview by using this where condition ?

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_ALL_PATIENTS]
    @ID VARCHAR(50)
AS
    SELECT 
        [Patient_No] as 'Medical Record No',
        patient_Name as 'Patient Name',
        age as 'Patient Age',
        Mobile as 'Patient Mobile',
        Email as 'Patient Email',
        Address,
        Gendername as 'Gender',
        Patient_id as 'Patient ID',
        natname as 'Nationality',
        patient_Name_Arabic as 'Arabic Name'
    FROM 
        Patients
    INNER JOIN 
        gender on gender.genderid = Patients.Gender
    INNER JOIN
        nationality on nationality.natid = Patients.natid
    WHERE 
        Patient_Name + patient_Name_Arabic + CONVERT(VARCHAR, [Age]) LIKE '%' + @ID + '%'
```

I have search textbox in my application i need to search data but first load i need to show all data to datagridview

This is the parameter calling code :

```
public DataTable GET_ALL_PATIENTS(string ID)
{
            DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlParameter[] Param = new SqlParameter[1];
            Param[0] = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            Param[0].Value = ID;
            dt = DAL.SelectData("GET_ALL_PATIENTS", Param);
            DAL.close();
            return dt;

        }
```

this is the code when open the page

```
 this.patientsGrid.DataSource = patient.GET_ALL_PATIENTS("");
```

what is the error how to solve this issue ?

Comment: `@ID varchar(50)`, why not `nvarchar` ?

Comment: What does `Patient_Name+patient_Name_Arabic+convert(varchar,[Age]) ` mean? Why are you concatenating a name and an an age?

Comment: This is old design and the other columns like patient_Name declared varchar , i tried to change it the @ID to nvarchar but also same error not showing all date i tried to convert nvarchar to varchar by using cast(patient_Name_Arabic as varchar(max)) but same result

Comment: in SQL any concatenation e.g. `Patient_Name + patient_Name_Arabic` where one of the values is null results in null. You need to handle null values e.g. `Patient_Name + coalesce(patient_Name_Arabic,'')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is CONCAT\_NULL\_YIELDS\_NULL a default setting in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32654178/why-is-concat-null-yields-null-a-default-setting-in-sql-server)

Comment: @mjwills I make search in the data ID first = null to show all data then i search by patient name english or arabic name or patient age by using this where condition i will pass the search criteria in my grid , I will add screenshot

Comment: `Patient_Name + patient_Name_Arabic + CONVERT(VARCHAR, [Age]) ` What are you really trying to do there? do you have `NULL`s in any of those columns?

Comment: You should use separate searches on each field rather than concatenate them like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be direct to your question, try this `ISNULL(patient_Name_Arabic, N'')`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_ALL_PATIENTS]
    @ID NVARCHAR(50)
AS
    SELECT 
        [Patient_No] as 'Medical Record No',
        patient_Name as 'Patient Name',
        age as 'Patient Age',
        Mobile as 'Patient Mobile',
        Email as 'Patient Email',
        Address,
        Gendername as 'Gender',
        Patient_id as 'Patient ID',
        natname as 'Nationality',
        patient_Name_Arabic as 'Arabic Name'
    FROM 
        Patients
    INNER JOIN 
        gender on gender.genderid = Patients.Gender
    INNER JOIN
        nationality on nationality.natid = Patients.natid
    WHERE 
        Patient_Name + ISNULL(patient_Name_Arabic, N'') + CONVERT(VARCHAR, [Age]) LIKE '%' + @ID + '%'
```

But maybe you need to re-think your query to avoid that concatenation step, that may hurt your query performance, or think about creating a persisted computed column on your table.

I think, the problem you are experiencing is because you have rows with null value in that column. When you are concatenating with other columns that will result in a null and (by default the connection CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL option is ON on SQL server) your query will skip those rows from your result.

Comment: I added ISNULL(patient_Name_Arabic, '') , now all data appeared in datagridview , but when i search by patient_name_arabic its not filter and show results its not pass data to ID and where condition ?

Comment: @Abdullah, I think you must make your `@ID` parameter `NVARCHAR` too, same in your where predicate... I'm not sure about your sproc input... may be in reality you need something like this instead? `WHERE (Patient_Name + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Age]) LIKE '%' + @ID + '%') OR (ISNULL(patient_Name_Arabic, N'') + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), [Age]) LIKE '%' + @ID + '%')`

Comment: Thank you so much now its working and filter , i changed ID to Nvarchar in stored procedure and parameter also                                                                 
  Param[0] = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            Param[0].Value = ID;

Comment: You are welcome @Abdullah. I'm going to update the answer with that.